# Safebrowse.io warning - Some users on home network can only connect to website after removing the "s" from https and proceed

Tags: networking, ssl, website, https

A company website I occasionally assist with is giving the following an error and it is only showing itself on home networks. Upon visiting the site, a user may experience the following error

```
The Site can't provide a secure connection.
<my-site> sent an invalid response
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

If a user clicks in the address bar, the site is using https. The user can delete the "s", press Enter, and they will be taken to the following screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JddVl.png

Once the user clicks Proceed anyway, they are taken to our site and no longer experience issue in the future. Reading through forums, I am wondering if this could be specific to Xfinity/Comcast internet provider? The URL for the "Proceed Anyway" screen is a safebrowse.io/warn

Comment: The server does not have HTTPS set up properly. Note that Safebrowse.io will only come up for Mac OS users, so that may explain why only some users are encountering what you describe. please review the servers HTTPS configuration and certificates. without knowing what kind of server your company is using, we can't really tell you more.

Comment: You can use e.g. https://ssllabs.com to check a server's SSL setup.

Comment: thanks for the info, scanned the site and it came back with a B rating. Having the primary devs look into that. Will follow up here with solution if found. To clarify, we have users report the issue on Mac and Windows machines. Appreciate the insights, and will follow up